# EF6 Modelfirst and creating Database views on initialisation

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sql-view, ef-model-first

I'm pretty new to Entity Framework, and I might be having a hard time "asking the right question" on google. So i'll try here.

First some facts:

- I'm working on a project based on the Entity Framework 6.x.
- I'm using the Model First approach.
- The database is an SQL Server.

My challenge:

Every time my Unit Tests run, I'm dropping creating and seeding a test database using the `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TContext>` implementation. The Data Source is an (localdb)\v11.0 instance.

I've gotten to a point where I would like to map an entity to a database view. I can find plenty of material on how easy it is to do the mapping, but what I'm looking for is a way for the view to be applied to my test database upon database creation/initialization?

I'm trying to keep a pure Model First approach. Can anyone help with information on how the views (and Stored Procedures) can be created, when creating the database?

Answer (score 0):

not sure this can be done.

I recently open an issue on codeplex for similar stuff but related to Code First.

[The answer](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2410) was: "edit generated code by hand".

**In your case** this should be done by inspiring yourself of this post about [model first seed data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006152/how-to-seed-data-when-using-model-first-approach). Instead of seeding, you should send DDL creating view through `SQL(...)` method as suggested in the answer of cited issue.

BTW: if you think, as I, that such a support should be a good idea, feel free to upvote [code first support for view](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6210457-code-first-support-for-view), and/or to create a model first support for view.